# How to make std xslt file which transform and display xml file into treeview format?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

How to make **std xslt file** that will use any xml file and display result in treeview format, please check image. **xslt script should not depends on any input xml format**. Input xml file will be any...

Input XML file

```
<Root>
  <Machine model="xp" type="win" number="202221" >
    <Software>      
      <Application type="Dev" version="1.2.3" />
      <RAM runningMode="Running" Passive="false" SimulationAlgorithm="false" AlternativeTerminalInput="false" />
    </Software>  
  </Machine>
</Root>
```

Default XSLT file for any XML file

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <HTML>
    <HEAD>
      <STYLE>
        BODY {font:x-small 'Verdana'; margin-right:1.5em}
      <!-- container for expanding/collapsing content -->
        .c  {cursor:hand}
      <!-- button - contains +/-/nbsp -->
        .b  {color:red; font-family:'Courier New'; font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none}
      <!-- element container -->
        .e  {margin-left:1em; text-indent:-1em; margin-right:1em}
      <!-- comment or cdata -->
        .k  {margin-left:1em; text-indent:-1em; margin-right:1em}
      <!-- tag -->
        .t  {color:#990000}
      <!-- tag in xsl namespace -->
        .xt {color:#990099}
      <!-- attribute in xml or xmlns namespace -->
        .ns {color:red}
      <!-- attribute in dt namespace -->
        .dt {color:green}
      <!-- markup characters -->
        .m  {color:blue}
      <!-- text node -->
        .tx {font-weight:bold}
      <!-- multi-line (block) cdata -->
        .db {text-indent:0px; margin-left:1em; margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
             padding-left:.3em; border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC; font:small
Courier}
      <!-- single-line (inline) cdata -->
        .di {font:small Courier}
      <!-- DOCTYPE declaration -->
        .d  {color:blue}
      <!-- pi -->
        .pi {color:blue}
      <!-- multi-line (block) comment -->
        .cb {text-indent:0px; margin-left:1em; margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
             padding-left:.3em; font:small Courier; color:#888888}
      <!-- single-line (inline) comment -->
        .ci {font:small Courier; color:#888888}
        PRE {margin:0px; display:inline}
      </STYLE>

      <SCRIPT><xsl:comment><![CDATA[
        // Detect and switch the display of CDATA and comments from an
inline view
        //  to a block view if the comment or CDATA is multi-line.
        function f(e)
        {
          // if this element is an inline comment, and contains more than a
single
          //  line, turn it into a block comment.
          if (e.className == "ci") {
            if (e.children(0).innerText.indexOf("\n") > 0)
              fix(e, "cb");
          }

          // if this element is an inline cdata, and contains more than a
single
          //  line, turn it into a block cdata.
          if (e.className == "di") {
            if (e.children(0).innerText.indexOf("\n") > 0)
              fix(e, "db");
          }

          // remove the id since we only used it for cleanup
          e.id = "";
        }

        // Fix up the element as a "block" display and enable
expand/collapse on it
        function fix(e, cl)
        {
          // change the class name and display value
          e.className = cl;
          e.style.display = "block";

          // mark the comment or cdata display as a expandable container
          j = e.parentElement.children(0);
          j.className = "c";

          // find the +/- symbol and make it visible - the dummy link
enables tabbing
          k = j.children(0);
          k.style.visibility = "visible";
          k.href = "#";
        }

        // Change the +/- symbol and hide the children.  This function works
on "element"
        //  displays
        function ch(e)
        {
          // find the +/- symbol
          mark = e.children(0).children(0);

          // if it is already collapsed, expand it by showing the children
          if (mark.innerText == "+")
          {
            mark.innerText = "-";
            for (var i = 1; i < e.children.length; i++)
              e.children(i).style.display = "block";
          }

          // if it is expanded, collapse it by hiding the children
          else if (mark.innerText == "-")
          {
            mark.innerText = "+";
            for (var i = 1; i < e.children.length; i++)
              e.children(i).style.display="none";
          }
        }

        // Change the +/- symbol and hide the children.  This function work
on "comment"
        //  and "cdata" displays
        function ch2(e)
        {
          // find the +/- symbol, and the "PRE" element that contains the
content
          mark = e.children(0).children(0);
          contents = e.children(1);

          // if it is already collapsed, expand it by showing the children
          if (mark.innerText == "+")
          {
            mark.innerText = "-";
            // restore the correct "block"/"inline" display type to the PRE
            if (contents.className == "db" || contents.className == "cb")
              contents.style.display = "block";
            else contents.style.display = "inline";
          }

          // if it is expanded, collapse it by hiding the children
          else if (mark.innerText == "-")
          {
            mark.innerText = "+";
            contents.style.display = "none";
          }
        }

        // Handle a mouse click
        function cl()
        {
          e = window.event.srcElement;

          // make sure we are handling clicks upon expandable container
elements
          if (e.className != "c")
          {
            e = e.parentElement;
            if (e.className != "c")
            {
              return;
            }
          }
          e = e.parentElement;

          // call the correct function to change the collapse/expand state
and display
          if (e.className == "e")
            ch(e);
          if (e.className == "k")
            ch2(e);
        }

        // Dummy function for expand/collapse link navigation - trap onclick
events instead
        function ex() 
        {}

        // Erase bogus link info from the status window
        function h()
        {
          window.status=" ";
        }

        // Set the onclick handler
        document.onclick = cl;

      ]]></xsl:comment></SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY class="st"><xsl:apply-templates/></BODY>

  </HTML>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Templates for each node type follows.  The output of each template has
a similar structure
  to enable script to walk the result tree easily for handling user
interaction. -->

<!-- Template for the DOCTYPE declaration.  No way to get the DOCTYPE, so we
just put in a placeholder -->
<!--  no support for doctypes
<xsl:template match="node()[nodeType()=10]">
  <DIV class="e"><SPAN>
  <SPAN class="b">&#160;</SPAN>
  <SPAN class="d">&lt;!DOCTYPE <xsl:value-of select="name()"/><I> (View
Source for full doctype...)</I>&gt;</SPAN>
  </SPAN></DIV>
</xsl:template>
-->

<!-- Template for pis not handled elsewhere -->
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
  <DIV class="e">
  <SPAN class="b">&#160;</SPAN>
  <SPAN class="m">&lt;?</SPAN><SPAN class="pi"><xsl:value-of
select="name()"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="."/></SPAN><SPAN
class="m">?&gt;</SPAN>
  </DIV>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Template for the XML declaration.  Need a separate template because the
pseudo-attributes
    are actually exposed as attributes instead of just element content, as
in other pis -->
<!--  No support for the xml declaration
<xsl:template match="pi('xml')">
  <DIV class="e">
  <SPAN class="b">&#160;</SPAN>
  <SPAN class="m">&lt;?</SPAN><SPAN class="pi">xml <xsl:for-each
select="@*"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>="<xsl:value-of select="."/>"
</xsl:for-each></SPAN><SPAN class="m">?&gt;</SPAN>
  </DIV>
</xsl:template>
-->

<!-- Template for attributes not handled elsewhere -->
<xsl:template match="@*" xml:space="preserve"><SPAN><xsl:attribute
name="class"><xsl:if
test="starts-with(name(),'xsl:')">x</xsl:if>t</xsl:attribute> <xsl:value-of
select="name()" /></SPAN><SPAN class="m">="</SPAN><B><xsl:value-of
select="."/></B><SPAN class="m">"</SPAN></xsl:template>

<!-- Template for attributes in the xmlns or xml namespace -->
<!--  UNKNOWN
<xsl:template match="@xmlns:*|@xmlns|@xml:*"><SPAN class="ns"> <xsl:value-of
select="name()"/></SPAN><SPAN class="m">="</SPAN><B class="ns"><xsl:value-of
select="."/></B><SPAN class="m">"</SPAN></xsl:template>
-->

<!-- Template for attributes in the dt namespace -->
<!-- UNKNOWN
<xsl:template match="@dt:*|@d2:*"><SPAN class="dt"> <xsl:value-of
select="name()"/></SPAN><SPAN class="m">="</SPAN><B class="dt"><xsl:value-of
select="."/></B><SPAN class="m">"</SPAN></xsl:template>
-->

<!-- Template for text nodes -->
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <DIV class="e">
  <SPAN class="b">&#160;</SPAN>
  <SPAN class="tx"><xsl:value-of select="."/></SPAN>
  </DIV>
</xsl:template>


<!-- Note that in the following templates for comments and cdata, by default
we apply a style
  appropriate for single line content (e.g. non-expandable, single line
display).  But we also
  inject the attribute 'id="clean"' and a script call 'f(clean)'.  As the
output is read by the
  browser, it executes the function immediately.  The function checks to see
if the comment or
  cdata has multi-line data, in which case it changes the style to a
expandable, multi-line
  display.  Performing this switch in the DHTML instead of from script in
the XSL increases
  the performance of the style sheet, especially in the browser's
asynchronous case -->

<!-- Template for comment nodes -->
<xsl:template match="comment()">
  <DIV class="k">
  <SPAN><A class="b" onclick="return false" onfocus="h()"
STYLE="visibility:hidden">-</A> <SPAN class="m">&lt;!--</SPAN></SPAN>
  <SPAN id="clean" class="ci"><PRE><xsl:value-of select="."/></PRE></SPAN>
  <SPAN class="b">&#160;</SPAN> <SPAN class="m">--&gt;</SPAN>
  <SCRIPT>f(clean);</SCRIPT></DIV>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Template for cdata nodes -->
<!-- UNSUPPORTED
<xsl:template match="cdata()">
  <DIV class="k">
  <SPAN><A class="b" onclick="return false" onfocus="h()"
STYLE="visibility:hidden">-</A> <SPAN class="m">&lt;![CDATA[</SPAN></SPAN>
  <SPAN id="clean" class="di"><PRE><xsl:value-of select="."/></PRE></SPAN>
  <SPAN class="b">&#160;</SPAN> <SPAN class="m">]]&gt;</SPAN>
  <SCRIPT>f(clean);</SCRIPT></DIV>
</xsl:template>
-->


<!-- Note the following templates for elements may examine children.  This
harms to some extent
  the ability to process a document asynchronously - we can't process an
element until we have
  read and examined at least some of its children.  Specifically, the first
element child must
  be read before any template can be chosen.  And any element that does not
have element
  children must be read completely before the correct template can be
chosen. This seems 
  an acceptable performance loss in the light of the formatting
possibilities available 
  when examining children. -->

<!-- Template for elements not handled elsewhere (leaf nodes) -->
<xsl:template match="*">
  <DIV class="e"><DIV STYLE="margin-left:1em;text-indent:-2em">
  <SPAN class="b">&#160;</SPAN>
  <SPAN class="m">&lt;</SPAN><SPAN><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:if
test="starts-with(name(),'xsl:')">x</xsl:if>t</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of
select="name()"/></SPAN> <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/><SPAN class="m">
/&gt;</SPAN>
  </DIV></DIV>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Template for elements with comment, pi and/or cdata children -->
<xsl:template match="*[comment() | processing-instruction()]">
  <DIV class="e">
  <DIV class="c"><A href="#" onclick="return false" onfocus="h()"
class="b">-</A> <SPAN class="m">&lt;</SPAN><SPAN><xsl:attribute
name="class"><xsl:if
test="starts-with(name(),'xsl:')">x</xsl:if>t</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of
select="name()"/></SPAN><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/> <SPAN
class="m">&gt;</SPAN></DIV>
  <DIV><xsl:apply-templates/>
  <DIV><SPAN class="b">&#160;</SPAN> <SPAN
class="m">&lt;/</SPAN><SPAN><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:if
test="starts-with(name(),'xsl:')">x</xsl:if>t</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of
select="name()"/></SPAN><SPAN class="m">&gt;</SPAN></DIV>
  </DIV></DIV>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Template for elements with only text children -->
<xsl:template match="*[text() and not(comment() |
processing-instruction())]">
  <DIV class="e"><DIV STYLE="margin-left:1em;text-indent:-2em">
  <SPAN class="b">&#160;</SPAN> <SPAN
class="m">&lt;</SPAN><SPAN><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:if
test="starts-with(name(),'xsl:')">x</xsl:if>t</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of
select="name()"/></SPAN><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  <SPAN class="m">&gt;</SPAN><SPAN class="tx"><xsl:value-of
select="."/></SPAN><SPAN class="m">&lt;/</SPAN><SPAN><xsl:attribute
name="class"><xsl:if
test="starts-with(name(),'xsl:')">x</xsl:if>t</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of
select="name()"/></SPAN><SPAN class="m">&gt;</SPAN>
  </DIV></DIV>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Template for elements with element children -->
<xsl:template match="*[*]">
  <DIV class="e">
  <DIV class="c" STYLE="margin-left:1em;text-indent:-2em"><A href="#"
onclick="return false" onfocus="h()" class="b">-</A> <SPAN
class="m">&lt;</SPAN><SPAN><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:if
test="starts-with(name(),'xsl:')">x</xsl:if>t</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of
select="name()"/></SPAN><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/> <SPAN
class="m">&gt;</SPAN></DIV>
  <DIV><xsl:apply-templates/>
  <DIV><SPAN class="b">&#160;</SPAN> <SPAN
class="m">&lt;/</SPAN><SPAN><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:if
test="starts-with(name(),'xsl:')">x</xsl:if>t</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of
select="name()"/></SPAN><SPAN class="m">&gt;</SPAN></DIV>
  </DIV></DIV>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current OUTPUT

```
-<Root> -<Machine model="xp" type="win" number="202221"> -<Software> <Application type="Dev" version="1.2.3" /> <RAM runningMode="Running" Passive="false" SimulationAlgorithm="false" AlternativeTerminalInput="false" /> </Software> </Machine> </Root>
```

**Current output is correct but I am expecting output in std format shown in image** for given xml file[Note: XSLT Script should not depends on any xml file]

[image: Expected output for given xml file]

Comment: What should the HTML markup look like for that output?

Comment: I am expecting standard XSLT script which transform xml file and that shows xml data in tree format. HTML code should be included in script. Folder and red ball images are not necessary.

Comment: How does what you want differ from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758684/how-to-create-treeview-from-xml-data-using-xslt or http://forums.asp.net/t/1604295.aspx or the other hits when one websearches "xslt treeview"?

Comment: This script currently gives me this output    -<Root>
-<Machine model="xp" type="win" number="202221">
-<Software>
 <Application type="Dev" version="1.2.3" />
 <RAM runningMode="Running" Passive="false" SimulationAlgorithm="false" AlternativeTerminalInput="false" />
 </Software>
 </Machine>
 </Root>    but I am expecting output format same as shown in image. The links you have provided gives me same output as currently I have. I am expecting std output same as image. Script gives me currect output in tree format but not std like image I shown.

Comment: @keshlam, is it possible? if not is there any another solution?suggestion?

Comment: It certainly should be possible. I haven't had time to sketch it, which is why I pointed toward possible existing solutions.

Comment: @Keshlam, If you don't have time, is it possible you to forward this question to another person who had knowledge of it?

Comment: Not for free, no. Either someone else here will get to it eventually, or I'll get to it eventually, or you'll look at the cited references eventually...